# Excel VBA JSON POST Loop

Tags: json, excel, vba, post

What i'm trying to accomplish is to go through a specific Table Column and for each visible row return the value of that cell. This cell contains a formula that creates a JSON from values in the table in other columns. Here's an example of the column i want to loop through:

[Json Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5obHy.png)

Inside this loop i'm going to use each cell value and POST the JSON, but it needs to loop through and post for each cell in that columnn. Here is the VBA code I'm using to POST a single cell without the loop:

```
Sub FulcrumUpload()

Dim xhr As Object, thisRequest As String, JSONvalue As String

Set xhr = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
thisRequest = "https://api.fulcrumapp.com/api/v2/records.json"

xhr.Open "POST", thisRequest, False
xhr.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
xhr.setRequestHeader "X-ApiToken", "11111111111111"

xhr.Send Sheets("Fulcrum Upload").Range("V3").value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your filtered data is in column V, from V3 onwards, perhaps something like:

```
Public Sub FulcrumUpload()
    Dim xhr As Object, thisRequest As String, rng As Range

    Set xhr = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    thisRequest = "https://api.fulcrumapp.com/api/v2/records.json"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fulcrum Upload")
        For Each rng In .Range("V3:V" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
            If Not IsEmpty(rng) Then
                With xhr
                    .Open "POST", thisRequest, False
                    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
                    .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
                    .setRequestHeader "X-ApiToken", "11111111111111"
                    .send rng.Value
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for responding so quickly

Comment: New Question Related to this:

Comment: Sorry I added it to the original question

Comment: Do i need to start a new question?

Comment: Did you really want two loops or did you just want if col Y empty then take value from Z? And yes it should be a new question.

Comment: I need the value from both the Y column and the Z column. The Y column value is the .send and the Z column value has to go into the REQUEST URL

Comment: One loop of Y and use offset(,1) to grab Z within the same loop

Comment: If i post it as a new question will you respond with the answer as I don't know how to do the offset. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Sure thing. Please edit this question back to how it was.

Comment: Will do. Here's the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063350/excel-vba-put-json